# Convert Date to pandas from ISO 8601 format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date it look like this

```
2021-12-14T20:32:34Z
```

how can i convert it to someting like this

```
2021-12-14 20:32
```

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime(s).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` where `s` is the regarded series with formatted strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this using Pandas, you can use pandas to convert iso date to [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) object then strftime to convert timestamp into string format

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

iso_date = '2021-12-14T20:32:34Z'
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
pd.to_datetime(iso_date).strftime(fmt)
```

to apply it to a series of dates of DataFrame column you can replace `iso_date` with the series of dates and use this code

```
pd.to_datetime(iso_date).dt.strftime(fmt)
```